# Find the distance between the circumcenter and the incenter of a triangle using trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Consider the following triangle:
[image]

As shown in the picture, the circum-radius of triangle $ABC$ is $R$ and its in-radius is $r$. How can we use trigonometric identities to prove that the value of $d$ is given by $$d=\sqrt{R^2 - 2Rr} ,$$ using the angles at the three vertices at the triangle (angles $A, B$ and $C$ respectively)?

---

I'm aware that there is a famous proof of this (known as [Euler's Theorem in geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_in_geometry)), but I came across this question while going through a chapter about the properties of a triangle, where it is specifically mentioned in the question that we must consider the angles at the respective vertices as $A, B$ and $C$. This made me think that it should be solved using trigonometry. I can't think of how I can get started. Any hints/working will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: use law of sines and the fact that incenter is the intersection of angle bisectors.

Comment: @Vasya I did have those in mind, but I'm unable to proceed any further. Another hint/explanation would really help, thanks!

Comment: you can use $\triangle AOI$ with $AI=d/ \sin \frac{\angle A}{2}$ and $AO=R$ you only need to find cosine of $\angle IAO$.